# Is is ok to have weak self in viewDidLoad

Tags: swift, self, viewdidload

I am implementing this drop down menu from cocoaPod. It is pretty easy to implement and I got it to work. 
https://github.com/PhamBaTho/BTNavigationDropdownMenu
However, as per instruction, I have implemented the following functions in viewDidLoad

```
        self.navigationItem.titleView = menuView
    menuView.didSelectItemAtIndexHandler = {[weak self] (indexPath: Int) -> () in
        print("Did select item at index: \(indexPath)")

        if indexPath == 0 {
            print("Closest")
            self?.sortByDistance()
        } else if indexPath == 1 {
            print("Popular")
            self?.sortByRatings()
        } else if indexPath == 2 {
            print("My Posts")
            self?.myPosts()
        } else {

        }
```

I am abit concerned as Xcode is telling me to put a ? or a ! just after self which was never done in other places of my program. Could someone please advise if this is totally acceptable or is there a better way of doing it? It just seems odd force unwrapping or putting my VC as optional...?

Answer (score 0):

The whole point of `{[weak self] ...` is that the controller may be released and you don't want this block to strongly capture it and keep it in memory if it has been released by whatever presented it. As such the reference to self may be nil.

So, you definitely don't want to use `!`, and you should either user `?` or and `if let` check.